# php apostrophe and quotations

Tags: php

```
echo "<tr><td><input type = 'button' value = 'Agregar' onclick = 'addrow($leaguesarray[$numofleagues])' /></td></tr></table><br />\n";
```

I have the above php code which is failing to call the addrow function I'm pretty sure its because of my quutoes.

```
echo "<tr><td><input type = 'button' value = 'Agregar' onclick = 'addrow('5a7')' /></td></tr></table><br />\n";
```

This also gives me errors I don't understand whats going on please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the single quotes inside that function call:

```
echo '<tr><td><input type = "button" value = "Agregar" onclick = "addrow(\'5a7\')" /></td></tr></table><br />\n';
```

With a PHP Var:

```
echo '<tr><td><input type = "button" value = "Agregar" onclick = "addrow(\'' . $leaguesarray[$numofleagues] . '\')" /></td></tr></table><br />\n';
```

Comment: that worked however what If I wanted to put a php variable inside of the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
echo "<tr><td><input type = \"button\" value = \"Agregar\" onclick = \"addrow('$leaguesarray[$numofleagues]')\" /></td></tr></table><br />\n";
```

Comment: Why escape all those, when you can just escape the ones inside the function call?

Comment: just to emphasize that the error is in escaping the quotations.